# Does PowerShell import function as module command by naming convention?

Tags: powershell

I have a PS module and in the .psm1 file for this module all relevant .ps1 files are "dot-sourced", or in my vocabulary: loaded. In one of the .ps1 files, let us say I have a function `SetFoo`.

If I do an `Import-Module` I cannot use the `SetFoo` function. If I list the commands for the module via `Get-Command` it is not available.

If I change the name of the function to `Set-Foo` the function is recognized after having done `Import-Module` and it is listed via `Get-Command`.

So my question is: is it via function naming convention that `Set-Foo` is loaded and `SetFoo` is not?  I have googled myself silly, but cannot find anything in the PS docs about this.

Comment: You may (re-)read the help for [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-5.1) ... and there the part about the function names. ;-)

Comment: Yes, it says that I should use the verb-noun naming, but I can't find anything about only properly named functions being selected for being a command of a module? What constitutes or determines a "command"?

Comment: Adding to Olaf's point, you also need to fix the scopes of the Functions. PS follows the cmdlets as Verb-Noun. Try to use that naming convention going forward

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the naming convention. My question was if the naming convention is what determines if a function is available from a module or if there is some other mechanism that I am not aware about.

Comment: @Viktor I just tried out your problem on my local machine and it seems to be working fine, both `Set-Foo` and `SetFoo` can be used.  
You sure it's not just a typo?

Comment: @sahus Is `SetFoo` (without dash) listed when you do `Get-Command` on your module?